# Bash File/Folder Permission Issue on Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, bash, chmod, mkdir

`mkdir` creates folders with 777 permission by default. How can I make 755 default?

Also when I clone a git repository all the files and folders are downloaded with 777 permission! How can I correct this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Here's a guide : https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

For your case, setting rwx-rx-rx (755) you can run the command: chmod 755 mydir.

Comment: I know how to run chmod. My question is not about how set permissions on files and folders. In Win 10 bash, there is a problem, and all files generated within the bash has 777 by default. New folders has 777 too. I would like to understand why this happens and fix this problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Workaround is add

```
umask 022
```

to `.bashrc` or similar.

Comment: this is the correct answer, also small typo, its umask not unmask

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/81#issuecomment-207553514

The short version (assuming I'm interpreting it correctly) is 0777 is applied to everything under the mnt; however, anything in ~ is fair game. The file or directory needs to stay there though or it will revert back to 0777 when you move it into mnt.

Here is what I did to get the permissions to stick, but I'm not sure how to make it default to a specific permissions upon creation.

```
cd ~
cd ..
mv mnt/c/mydir/myfile.ext
chmod 755 myfile.ext
```

By the way, be sure you run WSL as administrator.